# php file_get_contents from text input

Tags: file-get-contents

using below code to generate random line from a text file.  Is there a way of setting the url of text file via a user text input? Sorry, total noob

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('https://mytextfileurl.com');
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);    
$randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);    
$randPhrase = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];
?>
```